# Apache dbutils vs Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, apache-commons-dbutils

**What are the pros and cons of using Apache Db Utils vs Hibernate ?**

How it will affect performance of program ?

Comment: any help ? appreciated

Answer (score 4):

DbUtils is a small in size, lightweight in memory and transparent (it also does what it says) library designed for making interactions with JDBC easier. Hibernate ORM is much more than this and mainly an Object/Relational mapping framework that supports the implementation of the persistence layer of an application.

Hibernate is considered to follow the [Data Mapper pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern) that suits better to complex data models. Another popular data access pattern that suits to simple data models is the [Active Record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern).